# Android Recycler view with rotated images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a relatively simple recycler view, with images to be picked by the user. Some of these images may be rotated through 90, 180, 270 degrees. I Have been unable to get images that are rotated to display correctly, they are alway clipped. The following images show how the view looks with a simple image both in its normal orientation (landscape) and also rotated through 90 degrees (portrait and clipped). Also, relevant sections of code attached. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

```
        @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PickerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) holder.itemView;
        // clear out any existing children
        parent.removeAllViews();

        final ImageView view = new ImageView(ActivityJigsaw.this);

        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.whitebox);
        view.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        if ((toggle & 1) == 0 ) view.setRotation(90f);
        toggle ^= 1;
        parent.addView(view, holder.viewLayoutParams);

    }
    class PickerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final FrameLayout.LayoutParams viewLayoutParams;
        private final FrameLayout.LayoutParams shadowLayoutParams;

        PickerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // generate layout parameters
            viewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

        }
    }
```

[image: Recycler Snap shot]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#CircularPositioning

Comment: Sumit, not sure this helps? I am just adding an ImageView to a FrameLayout and providing the view with a height of Wrap_Content. I am not in this instance using ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Sumit, My issue here is not that I cannot rotate the image, it is that containing FrameLayout is clipping the ImageView when it is rotated. If your links help with this issue, can you be more specific on how they help.